# Multiple Login with Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have been trying to create multiple auth login in laravel 5.0. Previously when I have been using laravel 4.2 I used https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth for multiple login. It worked great!. I tried integrating it in laravel 5.0 but I could not do it. Can anyone help me how do it? My requirement is, I need separate login sessions for user and admin.

Comment: Your best option is to get in touch with the author and ask him kindly to update the package given the release of Laravel 5, otherwise you've got to have your hand dirty.

Comment: I have just stumbled up on this question, I guess it may be solved but incase this helps anyone else [I answered a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921595/laravel-5-implement-multiple-auth-drivers/28921969#28921969).

Comment: Hi Ash, I rewrote few things in ollieread plugin and things are working fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved multiauth in laravel 5 by changing few things in ollieread multiauth. You could find my package here https://packagist.org/packages/sarav/laravel-multiauth