# Laravel 5 Implement multiple Auth drivers

Tags: php, authentication, reflection, laravel-5

## Synopsis

I am building a system with at least two levels of Authentication and both have separate User models and tables in the database.  A quick search on google and the only solution thus far is with a MultiAuth package that shoehorns multiple drivers on `Auth`.

## My goal

I am attempting to remove `Auth` which is fairly straight-forward. But I would like `CustomerAuth` and `AdminAuth` using a separate config file as per `config/customerauth.php` and `config\adminauth.php`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Solution

I'm assuming you have a package available to work on. My vendor namespace in this example will simply be: `Example` - all code snippets can be found following the instructions.

I copied `config/auth.php` to `config/customerauth.php` and amended the settings accordingly.

I edited the `config/app.php` and replaced the `Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider` with `Example\Auth\CustomerAuthServiceProvider`.

I edited the `config/app.php` and replaced the `Auth` alias with:

```
'CustomerAuth' => 'Example\Support\Facades\CustomerAuth',
```

I then implemented the code within the package for example `vendor/example/src/`.  I started with the ServiceProvider: `Example/Auth/CustomerAuthServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace Example\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider;
use Example\Auth\CustomerAuthManager;
use Example\Auth\SiteGuard;

class CustomerAuthServiceProvider extends AuthServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->alias('customerauth',        'Example\Auth\CustomerAuthManager');
        $this->app->alias('customerauth.driver', 'Example\Auth\SiteGuard');
        $this->app->alias('customerauth.driver', 'Example\Contracts\Auth\SiteGuard');

        parent::register();
    }

    protected function registerAuthenticator()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('customerauth', function ($app) {
            $app['customerauth.loaded'] = true;

            return new CustomerAuthManager($app);
        });

        $this->app->singleton('customerauth.driver', function ($app) {
            return $app['customerauth']->driver();
        });
    }

    protected function registerUserResolver()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable', function ($app) {
            return $app['customerauth']->user();
        });
    }

    protected function registerRequestRebindHandler()
    {
        $this->app->rebinding('request', function ($app, $request) {
            $request->setUserResolver(function() use ($app) {
                return $app['customerauth']->user();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then I implemented: `Example/Auth/CustomerAuthManager.php`

```
<?php namespace Example\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;
use Example\Auth\SiteGuard as Guard;

class CustomerAuthManager extends AuthManager
{
    protected function callCustomCreator($driver)
    {
        $custom = parent::callCustomCreator($driver);

        if ($custom instanceof Guard) return $custom;

        return new Guard($custom, $this->app['session.store']);
    }

    public function createDatabaseDriver()
    {
        $provider = $this->createDatabaseProvider();

        return new Guard($provider, $this->app['session.store']);
    }

    protected function createDatabaseProvider()
    {
        $connection = $this->app['db']->connection();
        $table = $this->app['config']['customerauth.table'];

        return new DatabaseUserProvider($connection, $this->app['hash'], $table);
    }

    public function createEloquentDriver()
    {
        $provider = $this->createEloquentProvider();

        return new Guard($provider, $this->app['session.store']);
    }

    protected function createEloquentProvider()
    {
        $model = $this->app['config']['customerauth.model'];

        return new EloquentUserProvider($this->app['hash'], $model);
    }

    public function getDefaultDriver()
    {
        return $this->app['config']['customerauth.driver'];
    }

    public function setDefaultDriver($name)
    {
        $this->app['config']['customerauth.driver'] = $name;
    }
}
```

I then implemented `Example/Auth/SiteGuard.php` (note the methods implemented have an additional site_ defined, this should be different for other Auth drivers):

```
<?php namespace Example\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Guard;

class SiteGuard extends Guard
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'login_site_'.md5(get_class($this));
    }

    public function getRecallerName()
    {
        return 'remember_site_'.md5(get_class($this));
    }
}
```

I then implemented `Example/Contracts/Auth/SiteGuard.php`

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

interface SiteGuard extends Guard {}
```

Finally I implemented the Facade; `Example/Support/Facades/Auth/CustomerAuth.php`

```
<?php namespace Example\Support\Facades;

class CustomerAuth extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'customerauth';
    }
}
```

---

A quick update, when trying to use these custom auth drivers with [phpunit](/questions/tagged/phpunit) you may get the following error:

```
Driver [CustomerAuth] not supported.
```

You also need to implement this, the easiest solution is override the `be` method and also creating a `trait` similar to it:

```
<?php namespace Example\Vendor\Testing;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

trait ApplicationTrait
{
    public function be(UserContract $user, $driver = null)
    {
        $this->app['customerauth']->driver($driver)->setUser($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ash.i am working on laravel 5.1.i have socialite login where i need custom authentication if you know can you post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934494/how-to-login-using-github-facebook-gmail-and-twitter-in-laravel-5-1