# Laravel 5 Separate Authentication for Admin

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 tables for users Users and BackendUsers - One for frontend users (regular users / customers) and one for backend users (admin). Take note that these 2 tables have different structures don't tell me to combine them and use ONE table.

I have two solutions in mind:

1. Is to duplicate / extend the Authentication to separate the Authentication for backend as seen here: [Laravel 5 Implement multiple Auth drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921595/laravel-5-implement-multiple-auth-drivers)
2. Is to create one more table lets say UserPivot. Wherein there's a column for user_id (integer), and user_type (enum('frontend', 'backend')).

My question is what is the best way to implement this? Do you have better solution?

I want the idea of number 1 since it separates the Authentication for the backend users and it separates the session as well.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth](https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth). Although it has not been updated for L5.

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw that sir. :D

Comment: No prob. Can't you consider creating a common table for the user authentication? Then depending on the user role/type, you can pull the related information.

Comment: Yup that's what I've said in my number 2 solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package that solves this problem. I used https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with an auth's infrastructure like this, where clients and admins need to login with the same authentication form. Client and Admin have each's table. The trick here is:

1. Create a join table between users and admin where a discriminator be used to identify the roll (exactly as @Jake-Opena said)
2. Extends Auth service provider in order to implement the way you can validate your credentials based in role:

   ```
   // returns an user or admin based on a role and id
   retrieveById($identifier); 

   // returns an user or admin based on a role and its credentials 
   retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)

   // returns an user or admin based on a role and its token
   retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)

   // validate the credentials agains the table data based in a role
   validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
   ```

Another way (ugly option) is, if you want to avoid to create a join table, is to create a new form's input where the user chooses which role be used to authenticate its credentials.